# ASP Repeater - Get generated element ID

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have an ASP Repeater that generate divs that will be later filled by a js script (the script draws a bar chart, for clarity sake). I need the id of those divs so the js script can target them. The script is started from code behind.

The Repeater is binded to a `List<List<Object>> Recordsaggregated`. The `List<Object>` contains the raw datas for my bar charts. There should be one chart per element in `List<List<Object>>` (so one call of the js function with the appropriate div in argument)

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="graphdivs">
    <ItemTemplate>     
      <div id="DivChart<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1%>" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In code behind :

```
foreach (var recordlist in Recordaggregated)
{      
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "graphscript", "loadGraph();", true);  
}
```

loadGraph should take a div ID in argument here, but I don't know how to get the IDs of the divs generated by the repeater, and how to get 'the right one', a div that isn't used by a previous call of the script.

Comment: `graphdivs.ClientID` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please ? ClientID is the ID of the repeater itself ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The Repeater Control does not have a ClientID in the DOM. So wrap the `Repeater` with a `div` with your own `ID`. And the ones inside the repeater (DivChart0, DivChart1) you named yourself and are not renamed by aspnet

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="graphdivs" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <ItemTemplate>     
     <div id="DivChart<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1%>" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;"></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```